# Is it possible to combine User Defined Aggregate Functions with Dataset.observe?

Tags: apache-spark

Can User Defined Aggregate Functions be used with Dataset.observe?

Spark's observe method looks like an interesting way to instrument a job, but I would like to add more complicated aggregations than what I find out of the box (e.g. sampling a column using a sketch).

For this I would need to be able to aggregate using UDFAs, but so far I've not found a way that runs successfully.

I have implemented an Aggregator, but so far both the following tricks fail:

```
session.udf().register("myAgg", functions.udaf(new MyAggregator(), Encoders.STRING()));
Column aggCol = functions.expr("myAgg(inputCol)");
```

OR

```
Column aggCol = functions.udaf(new MyAggregator(), Encoders.STRING()).apply(ds.col("inputCol"));
```

THEN

```
ds = ds.observe("foo", aggCol);
```

When a task completes, I get an exception due to some unserializable stuff in the task result:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 2) had a not serializable result: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection, value: <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ScalaAggregator, name: inputProjection, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ScalaAggregator, myAgg(input[5, string, true]))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.TypedImperativeAggregate;, size 1)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AggregatingAccumulator, name: typedImperatives, type: class [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.TypedImperativeAggregate;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AggregatingAccumulator, AggregatingAccumulator(id: 111, name: Some(Collected metrics), value: [empty row]))
    - writeExternal data
    - externalizable object (class org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult, org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult@7c17b6a8)
```